# assigning scriplet variable to javascript variable using JSTL/EL

Tags: javascript, jstl

Could someone please tell me how can I pass variable declared in scriplet can be assigned to javascript using jstl

Comment: eg: 
    <%
    name="";
    name=document.getElementById('name').value;//Please ignore typos
    /*Here an if condition is used to check name is null and to get name value 
    from bean class using javascript;*/   //`enter code here`
    %>

Comment: function loadVal() {   
    <%
    document.getElementByName("Sname").value="<%=name%>";//This is working
    %>
     }
Above is working but my requirement is to replace <%= with scriptlet
I tried using 
    <%
    document.getElementByName("Sname").value="<c:out value='${name'/>";
    %>

Comment: But this is not working..

Could you please help how can I replace <%= with c:out/jstl to make code security compliant

Comment: Please read above as well...
My requirement is to replace scriptlet <%= with JSTL. Please suggest how can I replace with JSTL and assign value to javascript varaible

Comment: add your comments into your question description